# How to remove the Square mouse pointer in WinForms in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022, designer

I have this strange issue with Visual Studio 2022. I have a Windows Forms app and in some forms I have a square as the mouse pointer. It doesn't let me do anything. I can't resize or move controls, etc.

[image: square mouse]

It's the same issue this user had: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo1oqg2Wl5k.

However, the solution he used doesn't works for me.

The forms that present this issue are derived from another form, such as this:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : maintenance
```

How can I get back a normal mouse cursor?

EDIT: The issue is in the form designer, not when running the app

Comment: This may sound trivial, but try restarting your computer. Also, make sure you're using the latest version of Visual Studio, and check for Windows updates.

Comment: I don't believe that's a a mouse-cursor (for one thing, it's impossible to screenshot a mouse-cursor because it isn't rendered in the frame-buffer, it's a modern-day _hardware sprite_) - anyway, that looks like a broken WPF tooltip to me.

Comment: @Dai https://i.imgur.com/7gumjUl.png

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'll bite - are you using a VM or Remote Desktop - or have a funky GPU or graphics driver set-up?

Comment: @Dai No I'm just using Greenshot, one of many programs that are able to capture the mouse cursor.

Comment: i think it's as @Dai said, a broken WPF tooltip or something, i'll just reinstall VS after i finish this project and see what happens

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That’s cheating though: those programs just paint the cursor image onto the screenshot from the framebuffer/compositor.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably some debug feature. Try building using release preset and run the executable without debugger and report back if that worked or not.